# Convert SQL to MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, converters

Convert

`DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 900`

to

`db.oshibka.remove( { ???: { $gt: 900 } } )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.oshibka.remove( { date : { $lt : <now-900> } } )
```

You just need to calculate the date that 900 before now and compare that to the field in you documents.